# Error registering VB6 dll in SysWOW64

Tags: dll, com, vb6, 32bit-64bit

I am working on a VB6 web application running on 64bit Windows Server 2008. I have had to modify one dll component, but I get an error when I try to register it on the 64bit machine.

The new dll registers successfully in the NT environment where I'm building it. The old dll, which was already in place in a directory below SysWOW64 when I started, can be unregistered and re-registered without issue.

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sps>regsvr32 UserServices.old.dll
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sps>regsvr32 /u UserServices.old.dll
```

But when I try to register the new dll, regsvr32 returns an error. I suspect from the message that the issue may be one of compatibility with the dlls already on the 64bit server.  The compile options specify "No compatibility".

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sps>regsvr32 UserServices.new.dll
```

*The module "UserServices.new.dll" failed to load. Make sure the binary is stored at the specified path or debug it to check for problems with the binary or dependent .DLL files.
The specified module could not be found.*

How can I find the source of the problem, given that the dll registers OK on the build machine?

Comment: It is a "file not found" kind of error, your DLL might depend on another DLL that isn't present or cannot be found.  You should also type `..\regsvr32` to ensure you use the 32-bit version of it.  And note that if you've configured VB6 to write the DLL to this directory then it won't actually be stored there, it is protected by UAC.  You can use SysInternals' ProcMon utility, it will show you Regsvr32 searching for a DLL and not finding it.  Do note that running VB6 in a web server app is troublesome, you at least have to force a 32-bit application pool.

Comment: Thanks, Hans. It looks like it was a missing DLL dependency.

Answer (score 0):

some dependencies are missing, use [dependencywalker](http://www.dependencywalker.com) to check the missing dependencies and install them.